# Find orbit of $1$ for $\sigma$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

$\sigma = \left( \begin{array}{cc}1&2&3&4&5&6\\3&1&4&5&6&2\end{array}\right)$

$ 1 \mathop{\rightarrow}^{\sigma} 3 \mathop{\rightarrow}^{\sigma} 4 \mathop{\rightarrow}^{\sigma} 5 \mathop{\rightarrow}^{\sigma} 6 \mathop{\rightarrow}^{\sigma} 2 \mathop{\rightarrow}^{\sigma} 1 \mathop{\rightarrow}^{\sigma} \ldots$ following the notation in my book.

But the question asks the orbit of $1$, so is that the orbit containing one, or one orbit? If it is the orbit containing one it would be $\{1,3,4,5,6,2\}$

If that is not what is meant then I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Yes, orbit of $1$ is all the elements you visit when you repeatedly apply $\sigma$ to $1$.

Comment: okay thank you. my book likes to ask questions the chapter before. I read ahead but I wasn't entirely sure. thank you

Comment: This seems a reasonable use of the term "orbit", but I haven't seen it before. Perhaps something like the phrase "the orbit of $1$ under the group generated by $\sigma$" is more common?

Comment: @Travis: It's standard to talk about the orbit of some element of a set $X$ under $g$ where $g$ is an element of a group that acts on $X$. I checked Fraleigh *A First Course in Abstract Algebra* to confirm and found that this question is Exercise 8.10 from that book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the book says, the orbit of $1$ under $\sigma$ is the set $$\{\sigma^n(1) \mid n\in \Bbb Z\}$$

so you just need to look at $$\mathcal O_{1,\sigma} = \{\sigma^0(1) = 1, \sigma(1), \sigma^2(1), \ldots\}$$

and since, as you observed, $\sigma$ maps $$ 1 
\mapsto 3
\mapsto 4
\mapsto 5
\mapsto 6
\mapsto 2
\mapsto 1$$ the orbit of $1$ is the set containing all of these, which is $$\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$$

In short, your answer is correct.